# Kubernetes deployment with two replicas: One pod is running, the other fails

Tags: kubernetes

We have a deployment of a simple Node.js application with `replica=2`. The first pod comes up and is perfectly running, the second pod is in state `CrashLoopBackOff`, because its readiness probe failed:

> Readiness probe failed: Get http://100.107.65.32:8000/: dial tcp 100.107.65.32:8000: getsockopt: connection refused

Unfortunately, the logs are empty, no matter whether you specify `--previous` or not.

It can't be a problem with the container or the underlying image, since pod 1 works without any hassle. I have found https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62594, but that is open and the solution proposed there is rather a workaround than a fix, especially since it does not explain anything on *why* this happens.

Any ideas of how to proceed with this?

Comment: Can you check if it always fails on the same node? We had similar issue recently, and restarting a failing pod on different node solved it. It boiled down to local docker image repository being somehow inconsistent, and getting new image to that local node (failures were always on same node) solved the issue permanently. Also nothing in pod logs etc and connection refused error on readiness probe...

Comment: Could you share the kubelet log with events related to the second pod? Will it fail if you run this pod manually as a separate pod and not part of the deployment? Do you have enough resources to run a pod? (CPU, RAM, Disk space on the node) What will happen if you change the image of the deployment to something simple and reliable, e.g. nginx?

Comment: Thanks for all of your hints. Actually, the pod was just takings its time to start, and the probes started too early, when the pod was not yet ready. Increasing the initial delay helped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be solved

Actually, the pod was just takings its time to start, and the probes started too early, when the pod was not yet ready. Increasing the initial probe delay helped.